# NSMutableURLRequest setHTTPBody

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

i took this code from a different question and my script file has more inputs, not just mydata, also the data going into the mydata should not be static text, it should be from a NSString.

So my question is, how do i post multiple pieces of data to my script and how would I input a value from a NSString because my understand is i cannot use NSStrings with c data types. not sure if thats the correct terminology so please correct me if i am wrong.

```
const char *bytes = "mydata=Hello%20World";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/script.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:strlen(bytes)]];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
//NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", responseData];
NSLog(@"responseData: %@", responseData);

userData = responseData;
```

New issue using answer below

```
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data]; 

NSString *number = numberIB.text;
NSString *name = nameIB.text;

NSString *nameString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"name=", name];
NSString *numberString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"number=", number];

NSLog(nameString);
NSLog(numberString);

[data appendData:[nameString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[data appendData:[numberString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.siteaddress.com/test.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
//[request setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithBytes:data length:strlen(data)]];
[request setHTTPBody:data];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
//NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", responseData];
NSLog(@"responseData: %@", responseData);
```

the NSLogs for nameString and numberString come back name= and number= without any data. causing no data to be sent to my script.

Comment: Why not use a `NSMutableString` and then call `-dataUsingEncoding:` on that instead of using an `NSMutableData` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `NSMutableData` object to append bytes as needed, like so:

```
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data]; 
const char *bytes = "mydata=Hello%20World";
[data appendBytes:bytes length:strlen(bytes)];

//...

const char *moreBytes = "&someMoreData=Fantastic";

[data appendBytes:moreBytes length:strlen(moreBytes)];
```

**Edit:** If you want to append a `NSString` into the data buffer, you can use `-[NSString dataUsingEncoding:]` and pass it off to `-appendData:`

```
NSString *someString = @"blah";
[data appendData:[someString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:data];
```

Comment: how would i make it so i could have a NSString within the *bytes char

Comment: please see a updated problem using the information you have provided me.

Comment: @Mintuz, you forgot to add the format specifiers (`%@`) in the format strings passed to `-initWithFormat:`